# How do you redirect a PHP page to an IMG?

Tags: php, redirect, image, src

I have a blog background website.  We provide some HTML code that the user can insert into his page, and it has something like this:

<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />

Unfortunately, I have had to relocate the images from time to time.  Each time I have to relocate the image, the image no longer works for the people who have put the code into their site.

I am wondering if there is a way in PHP so that I can do something like this:

<img src="http://example.com/getImage.php?id=523" />

And have the getImage.php actually redirect to the actual image URL (looked up from my database with the given ID).  In this way, I can have one URL to give to the user, and if I ever need to relocate the image, I just do it in my database, and the user's background still works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can use the following to transparently serve a JPEG from php:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/path/to/file.jpg');
exit;
```

Alternatively, you can just redirect to the image URL:

```
header('Location: /web/path/to/file.jpg');
exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
header("Location: $url");
```

Comment: Oh wow, I thought I had tried that, but it turns out I had errors in my HTML.  Thanks!